# Excel formula: where value equals text and another value equals between values

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula, vlookup

I am trying to do a lookup using multiple values:
I need to lookup the type of car and then check the mileage that is between the values for each cost bracket in order to find out the cost for that distance traveled in the vehicle.

I understand the use of Vlookup, Index, Match and other formula but I am not sure how to use them in conjunction to get my answer. I do not want to add up the value if there is two people who are the same I just need the cost for that one rows trip.

Thanks, see image below

[image: an example of the data i'm working with]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your lookup to only include only the bottom threshold and use this formula:

```
=INDEX(G:H,MATCH(B2,F:F,0),MATCH(C2,$G$2:$H$2))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, this is exactly what i needed :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND([lookup condition 1], [lookup condition 2]), [return value if true], [return value if false])
```

Comment: Maybe i should have mentioned this but i hope to be able to apply this formula on up 100 different cost brackets, any easier way than to define them all?

Comment: Working on that now. One second.